# How do I now create a relationship in the model to get connected objects

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to refer to the same table? There is a model `ObjectType` with a table `object_types` and fields `id`, `name`. I created a linking table according to the scheme.

```
Schema::create('object_type_permissions', function (Blueprint $table) 
{
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('a_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('b_id');

        $table->foreign('a_id')->references('id')->on('object_types');
        $table->foreign('b_id')->references('id')->on('object_types');
        $table->primary(['a_id','b_id']);
});
```

How do I now create a relationship in the model to get connected objects?

Comment: see this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: there is no answer to my problem here(

Comment: on ObjectTypePermissions model:

public function objectType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ObjectType::class, 'id');
    }